# android visual clue/hint that long-tap is available for a control

Tags: user-expectation, hints, android, long-press

I am implemnting an [app that can tag photos](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/issues/25) The listview-items contain 3 image-buttons and a text.

If user long-taps on a list-view-item-button there will be additional functionality (menu or dialog).

Is there a standard/idea or some lib-functionality that can put a visual clue/hint on long-tappable items so that the user knows that he/she can do more?

On windows there is the convention that "..." means open a dialog/submenu with additional choises.

i am looking for some convention / lib-functionality that tells the user about that "long-tap" is available.

I will also put a description into the online-manual but from server access log i can see that nearly nobody reads it.

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945565/android-give-indication-that-menu-is-available

Comment: Is [this](https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/gesture-education.html#) the kind of solution you are looking for?

Comment: The link can be usefull to teach the user that every time he sees xxxx then he can long-tap to get further options.
My question is more like: how could xxxx look like? what have other gui-experts done or is there even a standard?

Comment: What you are showing is a tooltip, so you want to know if there is an icon or similar to hover/click and display the tooltip, right?

Comment: i have buttons: short-tap do some action. long-tap show a menu or dialog. example: imagine you have button "send with whatsapp". if you press the button (short tap) you send the content to "whatsapp". if you long tap you get a menu asking you "to what app do you want to send?". Note: my usecase is completely different. Note: normally android has no mouse so it has no hover.

Comment: You could use a button to open a tooltip, specially useful in touch devices. But  showing two kinds of tooltips depending on the press time, I'm not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: Is it mandatory that you wish to incorporate the functionality via only a long tap? Or would it be okay to use some sort of standard system icon that could indicate an extended menu? The reason I ask this is because users can only be educated about the gestures at distinct intervals (see [here](https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/gesture-education.html#gesture-education-targeting-triggering)) while using a standard system icon would require no learning curve for the user.

Answer (score 1):

### Always use single press untill unless it is taken by the primary action and for secondary action the user shall try longpress. this shall be hard for IOS users as they are not acquainted with this interaction though google apps in IOS follow their standards. You can give alternate interaction such as.

try something like google uses in its Gmail[image] and contacts apps.
 where you can directly **click on the left small circle** used to represent the user instead of **long-press**

---

Prefer using swipe actions for secondary interactions

---

or use some side arrow at the end of list and make some other interaction on clicking on that arrow.

---